# Kodak pneumatic self timer gasket replacement?

Tags: repair, kodak, self-timer

[image: kodak pneumatic self timer]

The gasket on the speed control mechanism needs replacement
because there are only two speeds possible.

Too fast when the control is tight.

Too slow if it is loosened a bit.

What materials will work for a replacement gasket?

The material must slow the passage of air.

The material must slow air passage more when tightly compressed,and allow more air when less compressed.

The compression of the material controls the speed at which air escapes.

[[image: kodak pneumatic self timer compressed][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTH1W.jpg)
Control dial removed.
[image: kodak pneumatic self timer with dial removed]

Dial showing deteriorated gasket.
[image: dial detail]
The gasket deteriorated gasket material looks a bit like tar.

But is not very sticky. Just slightly.
[image: dial detail]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127305/discussion-on-question-by-bob-macaroni-mcstevens-kodak-pneumatic-self-timer-gask).

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm sure some/many of the LF gurus over at the [Large Format Photography Forum](https://www.largeformatphotography.info/forum/) would have an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Most gaskets, especially those that also served as valves, were made of leather more than a century ago.  The old one may not look much like leather because it's been soaked with various kinds of oil for the past hundred years, but leather was used almost universally for this kind of application.

It should be possible to remove the old gasket (likely in tiny pieces), clean up the pocket, and cut a new gasket to fit from a suitable piece of soft leather (from an old shoe, purse, or baseball glove, football, basketball, or vollyball cover, if old enough, or what have you -- or from new leather, purchased from a leatherworking supplier).  Select leather a little thicker than the depth of the pocket.

Glue it in place with rubber cement or contact cement, and once the glue is thoroughly dry, put some neat's foot oil or similar leather dressing on the sealing surface to keep it soft.  Such a repair ought to work just like the original did when new, and with a little care, last another century.